# camera2 throws SecurityException

Tags: android

I am working with the camera2 api in android, and tried to switch between TextureView and SurfaceView, so the only change I made was to replace the TextureView with SurfaceView and the TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener with SurfaceHolder.Callback. and now all phones under android 7 are crashing. (I have the permissions needed and run-time permissions needed. - the app worked good before switching to SurfaceView).

the app crash in the line:

```
mPreviewBuilder = 
    mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
```

old code:

```
private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener
        = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {

    @Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture,
                                      int width, int height) {
    openCamera(width, height);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture,
                                        int width, int height) {
    configureTransform(width, height);
}

@Override
public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
}

};
/**
 * Start the camera preview.
 */
private void startPreview() {
    if (null == mCameraDevice || !mTextureView.isAvailable() || null == mPreviewSize) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        closePreviewSession();
        SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        assert texture != null;
        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
        mPreviewBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);

        Surface previewSurface = new Surface(texture);
        mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Collections.singletonList(previewSurface),
        new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    mPreviewSession = session;
                    updatePreview();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    if (null != activity) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }, mBackgroundHandler);
} catch (CameraAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

new code:

```
private SurfaceHolder.Callback mSurfaceViewListener =
        new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
                SurfaceViewLifeCycle.setSurfaceState(SurfaceViewLifeCycle.SURFACE_VIEW_LIFE_CYCLE_CREATED);
                openCamera(640, 480);
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
                SurfaceViewLifeCycle.setSurfaceState(SurfaceViewLifeCycle.SURFACE_VIEW_LIFE_CYCLE_DESTROYED);
                closeCamera();
            }
        };


    /**
 * Start the camera preview.
 */
private void startPreview() {
    if (null == mCameraDevice ||
            SurfaceViewLifeCycle.getSurfaceState() != SurfaceViewLifeCycle.SURFACE_VIEW_LIFE_CYCLE_CREATED ||
            null == mPreviewSize) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        closePreviewSession();
        //SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        //assert texture != null;
        //texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
        mPreviewBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        //Surface previewSurface = new Surface(texture);
        Surface previewSurface = mSurfaceView.getHolder().getSurface();
        mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Collections.singletonList(previewSurface),
                new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                        mPreviewSession = session;
                        updatePreview();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                        if (null != activity) {
                            Toast.makeText(activity, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }, mBackgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

the error log:

```
11-28 15:38:32.253 13516-13516/rifdsafsda.com.phase9try12 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: rifdsafsda.com.phase9try12, PID: 13516
                                                                            java.lang.SecurityException: Lacking privileges to access camera service
                                                                                at android.hardware.camera2.utils.CameraBinderDecorator.throwOnError(CameraBinderDecorator.java:108)
                                                                                at android.hardware.camera2.utils.CameraBinderDecorator$CameraBinderDecoratorListener.onAfterInvocation(CameraBinderDecorator.java:73)
                                                                                at android.hardware.camera2.utils.Decorator.invoke(Decorator.java:81)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393)
                                                                                at $Proxy1.createDefaultRequest(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.createCaptureRequest(CameraDeviceImpl.java:628)
                                                                                at rifdsafsda.com.phase9try12.media.camera.RecordingManager.startPreview(RecordingManager.java:282)
                                                                                at rifdsafsda.com.phase9try12.media.camera.RecordingManager.access$300(RecordingManager.java:41)
                                                                                at rifdsafsda.com.phase9try12.media.camera.RecordingManager$2.onOpened(RecordingManager.java:121)
                                                                                at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$1.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:134)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the camera permission has been granted after openCamera is called try this and check:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && 
ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
{
  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(AndroidCameraApi.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_ID);
}
else
{
     openCamera(640, 480);
}
```

Comment: Camera permission and all other permissions (write external storage, record audio etc) has been granted by the user in the previous activity, otherwise he won't be able to proceed to the camera activity

Comment: I found the problem, because the SurfaceView callback worked faster then the TextureView callback, the order of things (like cameraOpen etc) needed a change.

Comment: So when you called openCamera you didn't had the permission yet as I pointed, I hope you can synchronize your calls.

Comment: the problem was something else (I guess multiple calls to startPreview). thanks anyway.